# IntelliJ JSF GUI designer

Tags: user-interface, jsf-2, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ right now and I plan to use JSF, but i can't find any GUI designer for the xhtml file.  I know edit the code is good and all but I want to know if there is any plugin out there that at least let me see my layout design without having to run the site?

I see Netbean has some but I can't find one for IntelliJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA does not include a visual designer for JSF, and we're not aware of any third-party plugin providing that functionality.

Comment: :( okay, thank you ... more reason for me to love the Neatbean/Eclipse of the world